# while this.state is a Javascript object , why is state null even after passing into it a state that has data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code (see below)

I want it to display the username which is a combination of firstName and lastName . Why doesn't the below code work ?

I expect it to display

> Welcome Daggie Blanqx !

```
class Header extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName : 'Daggie',
            lastName :  'Blanqx',
            userName : ()=>(this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName)
        }


    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p> Welcome {this.state.userName} !</p>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `{this.state.userName()}`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're defining a function in your state?

Comment: your currently returning the function, you need to add parentheses e.g. **{this.state.userName()}** to invoke the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are inserting a function to your state and hence you need to call it to get the result. Generally putting functions like this in the state is not recommended. However, if you still want to go with that approach, try the following:

```
<p>Welcome , {this.state.userName()} !</p>
```

An even better approach would be to remove the function from the state and do like this:

```
getUserName() {
   return this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<p>Welcome , {this.getUserName()} !</p>
```

Comment: When we call functions in eventhandlers , we dont use () ...why is this case an excpetion ?

Comment: There are differences between react and vanilla javascriipt. For example in react you are passing references to functions. For example:
<div onClick={this.getUserName}></div>

Then when somebody actually does the click the component "div" will trigger the function which was passed into the onClick handler.

Compared to vanilla javascript where you pass strings which are evaluated when someone clicks on the div.

You can read more about it here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 4):

You are missing with ()

```
<p> Welcome {this.state.userName()} !</p>
```

Also no need to define a function for this directly get the result like this

```
<p>Welcome , {this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName} !</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example you are accessing the the function `this.state.userName` you need to call that like this `this.state.userName()`
`this.state.userName` will return the `function` variable you need to put `()` at end of your function get `return` value of the function
You you understood why its not working
**Try to avoid using methods in your state object**

Comment: Why do you say "Try to avoid using methods in your state object" ...is there a better way to call out userName from a firstName and a lastName ?

Comment: yes in this cause its ok but you have complex functions its not good i thnk

Answer (score 1):

It should throw an error because you're trying to interact with the state but state hasn't been initialized yet. For that purposes, use `componentDidMount()` + `prevState` or just put it inside `render()`:

**Variant 1**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstName : 'Daggie',
            lastName :  'Blanqx'
        }


    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p> Welcome {this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName} !</p>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

**Variant 2**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstName : 'Daggie',
            lastName :  'Blanqx',
            fullName: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        fullName: prevState.firstName + prevState.lastName
      }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <p> Welcome {this.state.fullName} !</p>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```